# DB2: Trim white space in CHARACTER column

Tags: database, db2, character

Is there is any way to trim white space in CHARACTER column in DB2 database without converting its type to varchar?

Comment: What's the goal / problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

no

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008470.html

> All values in a fixed-length string column have the same length, which is determined by the length attribute of the column.